# .Net-Core object property string(Month/Year) is dividing in JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have an object @application.MonthandYear that I'm sending to javascript to create another element. However, in javascript, the outcome of the property is divided value. Example: 08/21(month and year) I'm getting 0.33333..
I tried to send it like @application.MonthandYear.ToString() even in js to convert it to string but no luck.
Any ideas how can I fix this?

```
MonthYear.innerText = applicationMonthandYear.toString();

            @foreach (var application in @Model.DeclinedPayments)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@application.Id</td>
                    <td><a href="/User/Details/@application.UserId">@application.UserId</a></td>
                    <td>$@application.Amount</td>
                    <td><input type="password" value="@application.CardNumber" class="card-number-input" /></td>
                    <td>@application.MonthandYear</td>
                    <td>@application.Cvv</td>
                    <td>@application.DateCreated.ToLongDateString()</td>
                    <td>@application.Status</td>
                    <td>
                        <a onclick="PendingPayment(@application.Id, @application.UserId, @application.Amount,@application.CardNumber, @application.MonthandYear, this)"><i class="fas fa-question-circle fa-2x iicon"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }



   function PendingPayment(applicationId, applicationUserId, applicationAmount, applicationCardNum, applicationMonthandYear, ctrl) {
        ctrl.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        var baseUrl = "https://localhost:44380/Payment/Pending";
        var requestUrl = baseUrl + "?paymentId=" + applicationId;
        var data = {
            paymentId: applicationId
        };
        axios.post(requestUrl, data)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                var theTbody = document.getElementById("tbodyToAppend");
                var tr = document.createElement("tr");
                var ShowId = document.createElement("td");
                var UserId = document.createElement("td");
                var Amount = document.createElement("td");
                var CardNum = document.createElement("td");
                var MonthYear = document.createElement("td");


                ShowId.innerText = applicationId; 
                UserId.innerText = applicationUserId;
                Amount.innerText = applicationAmount;
                CardNum.innerText = applicationCardNum;
                MonthYear.innerText = applicationMonthandYear.toString("MM/yy");


                tr.appendChild(ShowId);
                tr.appendChild(UserId);
                tr.appendChild(Amount);
                tr.appendChild(CardNum);
                tr.appendChild(MonthYear);
                theTbody.appendChild(tr);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {

            })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you would probably need to send the month and year separately

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core most likely produces the following code:

```
<script>
    MonthYear.innerText = 25/3;
</script>
```

I think you'll need to wrap the statement with double quotes

```
MonthYear.innerText = "@applicationMonthandYear.ToString("MM/yy")";
```

In order to generate the following html

```
<script>
    MonthYear.innerText = "25/3";
</script>
```

Comment: "@applicationMonthandYear.ToString("MM/yy")" is out of scope for JS, since its in forloop. applicationMonthandYear is the parameter that is send from .Net core. I updated the post.

Comment: Better to take two different parameters in the PendingPayment method , then combine them as you like within the method.

Answer (score -1):

You can try `MonthYear.innerText = '@applicationMonthandYear.toString("MM/yy")';` When you are populating the value from a .Net variable, format the date as a string and then assign.

Comment: When I'm sending the property  @application.MonthandYear it's already a string, the problem is with JavaScript, it's dividing the values.

Comment: Its because its considering that as numbers and division, not string. Enclose them in single quotes, so JS will consider that as a string assignment not numbers to divide and evaluate. Update my answer, please check

Comment: if I try your way I will get a string of '@applicationMonthandYear.toString("MM/yy")', plus @applicationMonthandYear is asp.net parameter that is sent to JS. JS function has the parameter as applicationMonthandYear. I will update the post with JS function

Comment: How is your `PendingPayment` method called, and how are you passing the parameters in there?